# Sbt plugin publication and resolution on bintray, different paths (sbt-bintray plugin)

Tags: sbt, bintray, sbt-plugin

I have some troubles to publish/use a custom sbt plugin from bintray. I'm able
to publish `sbt-plugin` on bintray but when I try to use it the resolver uses
another path.

I have followed the [official guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) but adapted it to the latest version of the plugin, I have this `build.sbt` into my plugin :

```
lazy val commons = Seq(
  organization in ThisBuild := "me.my.app",
  version in ThisBuild := "0.1.0"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commons ++ BintrayPlugin.bintrayPublishSettings: _*).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    name := "sbt-plugin",
    description := "Share configuration and plugins accros app projects",
    bintrayOmitLicense := true,
    publishMavenStyle := false,
    bintrayRepository := "sbt-plugins",
    bintrayOrganization := None
  ).
  settings(
    addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "bintray-sbt" % "0.3.0"),
    addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.6.0"),
    addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" % "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.8.0")
  )
```

The `sbt-plugin> publish` task complete successfully and publish my plugin into
**me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/jars/sbt-plugin.jar**

Then I add `addSbtPlugin("me.my.app" % "sbt-plugin" % "0.1.0")` to `my-project\project\plugins.sbt` and
reload it. But he fail with

```
[warn] ==== bintray-{organization}-{repo}: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/{organization}/sbt-plugins/me/my/app/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.1.0/sbt-plugin-0.1.0.pom
...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: me.my.app#sbt-plugin;0.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      me.my.app:sbt-plugin:0.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      me.my.app:sbt-plugin:0.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/me/Projects/app/app-web/project/plugins.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:app-web-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: me.my.app#sbt-plugin;0.1.0: not found
 at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: me.my.app#sbt-plugin;0.1.0: not found
```

As you can see the URL used to download the plugin is not the same as the
one where the plugin has been published. (with `publishLocal` my plugin is
published under the same path but resolved successfully.

- Local : `me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/jars/sbt-plugin.jar`
- Upload : `me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/jars/sbt-plugin.jar`
- Downlad: `me/my/app/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.1.0/sbt-plugin-0.1.0.pom`

I have tried with or without `publishMavenStyle := false` and with `Resolver.bintrayRepo` and `Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo` but without success.

I will be missing something but I have to admit that I feel a bit lost. So what are the missing configuration that should align the *upload* and *download* paths ?

**Details :**

- `publishMavenStyle := false` -> **me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/jars/sbt-plugin.jar**
- `publishMavenStyle := true`  -> **me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/jars/sbt-plugin.jar**
- `Resolver.bintrayRepo` -> **me/my/app/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.1.0/sbt-plugin-0.1.0.pom**
- `Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo` -> **me.my.app/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publication part was ok. The only problem was on the resolution side.

I had to add a custom resolver with explicit *ivyStylePatterns* resolver into `my-project\build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("me @ bintray", url("https://dl.bintray.com/{my-bintray-account}/{my-bintray-generic-repo}"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```